# Capitalize first letter of a sentence in a placeholder

Tags: html, css, capitalization

Is it possible capitalize only "Date" in this situation without using js?

```
placeholder="date (dd/mm/yyyy)"
```

Comment: If you're not using JS, then your HTML is the start and endpoint. Just write `Date`, with a capital letter, and save your file?

Comment: this is what I did from the beginning
usually though, if I can, I try to leave the html as aseptic as possible, to have maximum control over the style, so I was curious about it

Comment: But HTML is what you put around your content for it to be marked up, and that placeholder is still content. Get that right first, and you don't _need_ CSS, which is the best kind of CSS. Stick with just content for as long as you can, CSS for the parts you can't, and JS for the parts that even CSS can't do, that way the browser has to do the least amount of work =)

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear we can use the `::first-letter` selector on an input to target the placeholder. However, you could achieve a near result using capitalize. See example below.

```css
input::placeholder {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="date (dd/mm/yyyy)" />
```

However, you could achieve the desired result using some simple JavaScript.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")
const placeholder = input.getAttribute("placeholder");              
input.setAttribute('placeholder', placeholder[0].toUpperCase() + placeholder.substring(1));
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="date (dd/mm/yyyy)" />
```

Comment: I meant only the first letter, in this way instead you have capitalized also Dd

Comment: Yes, as I said this is a near result.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) and [`:placeholder-shown`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/) (an alternative I considered at first), are very limited. The best non-JavaScript solution is to convey information by showing the details in markup by using `:focus-within` on a `<small>` like a pop-up (*see **Example 1** in snippet below -- click the input (focus) and then click elsewhere (unfocus)*).

Assuming that the `<input>` resides within a `<form>`, one line (*albiet a long line*), of JavaScript can rectify all `[placeholder]`s. Add a `[name]` with a shared value to all applicable `<input>` and `<textarea>`s in a `<form>` then use [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) and [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) interface to reference them all (*see **Example 2** in snippet below*).

**Note:** No solution is as simple as just changing one simple letter in a placeholder by editing the HTML itself. If there's a ton of them or they are dynamically added and you can't control the back-end, then **Example 2** is the best solution.

```js
[...document.forms.example2.elements.text] // Collect all [name="text"]
.forEach(text => text.placeholder = // Each [name="text"]["placeholder"] is now
  text.placeholder.charAt(0).toUpperCase() // "D" 
  + // AND
  text.placeholder.slice(1)); // "ate dd/mm/yyyy"
```

```css
/* General CSS */

html {
  font: 2ch/1.15 'Segoe UI'
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* Example 1 */

.example1 input::placeholder {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

small {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: tomato;
}

.example1:focus-within small {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Example 1</legend>
  <label class='example1'>
    <input placeholder='date*'> 
    <small>*dd/mm/yyyy</small>
  </label>
</fieldset>

<form name='example2'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Example 2</legend>
    <input name='text' placeholder='date dd/mm/yyyy'>
    <input name='text' placeholder='enter first name'>
    <textarea name='text' rows='3' cols='48' placeholder='instead of taking the time to capatalize your placeholders properly, use a little JavaScript.'></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```